# Error on a WordPress page (php file): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to this and I don't know php. I get this error on WordPress posts:

`Warning: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable in  /www/tastingvictoria_289/public/wp-content/themes/astra-child/single.php on line 32` Which where `if(count($related_article) > 0){?>` is.

Here is the file it is coming from. Is it a syntax thing?

Any cue? Thanks

```
    <div id="primary" <?php astra_primary_class(); ?>>
        <?php astra_primary_content_top(); ?>
        <?php
        $related_article = get_field( "select_article", 'option' );
        if(count($related_article) > 0){
        ?>
                <?php
                    ?>
                    <div class="article">
                        <div class="wrap">
                            <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>">
                                <div class="article-image" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $post_thumb; ?>);"></div>
                            </a>
                            <div class="infos">
                                <div class="infos-wrap">
                                    <p class="date"><?php echo $postdate; ?></p>
                                    <a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><h4 class="title"><?php echo $title; ?></h4></a>
                                    <p class="excerpt"><?php echo $excerpt; ?></p>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
        <?php   
        ?>

    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php if ( astra_page_layout() == 'right-sidebar' ) : ?>

    <?php get_sidebar(); ?>

<?php endif ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Explanation:**

The count() Method Counts all elements in an array when used with an array.
the condition: `count($related_article) > 0` checks if the array is not null.

therefore the variable `$related_article` must be an array.
php recognizes thats not an array and throws an error.
its not a syntax error but a missuse of the count() method.

php documentaion - https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php

**solution**

to fix this error i would try to change code `count($related_article) > 0`
to that `isset($related_article)`